# When shall I Post Two answers for the same question

Tags: discussion

i don't know If i did something wrong here on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28673567/3556874).

1. I posted an answer, which **wasn't** quite cross browser compatible.
2. OP accepted my answer reasoning that, it was cross browser compatible.
3. Another user(A good user), who also already answered the same question, commented that my answer was just as cross browser compatible as his answer was.
4. The OP accepted his answer(thats a good thing, because his answer was worthy of it).
5. I thought of another approach which could be cross browser compatible.
6. then I posted it as a different answer to the same question.

now here come an alert box, which asks me, if i really want to add another answer or i can just refine my previous answer by editing it.

I usually just edit my answer, if i want to add some more info to it. But this time I thought that my second answer, even if similar to first one, was addressing a different problem (browser compatibility), so i posted it as a different one.

1. Did i do anything wrong? shall i just merge my new answer with previous one?
2. if yes, why and what would be scenario to post a double answer, and
   why is there a post an answer button still active on the page even if I already answered it?

Comment: Sometimes it is possible, that you have two significantly different answer to the question.

There is also a possibility, that you answer a question, it gets accepted (from this point you can't delete this), but finally you find that bad or find a better answer, too.

I made here around 500 answers on the SE network, there was maybe 1-2 times when I created multiple answers. Thank you very much our wonderful admins to close this question in the last minute I've posted this answer.

Comment: did that once: got upvoted for the first answer, and heavily downvoted for the second one which was a big "what if" and didn't make much sense. I was happy to be able to delete that one :)